# EPSILON(CFG) = {<G,H> | G and H are CFGs where the concatenation is epsilon. is this language Turing-recognizable?

Tags: undecidability, turing-recognizable

It is given that the language is not decidable.
[image]

Is this language Turing-recognizable?

Comment: Hint: is the complement of $\mathsf{EPSILON}_{\mathsf{CFG}}$ Turing-recognizable?

Comment: I genuinely lost it and can't think of anything..

Comment: i understand all of the theorems around it.. but can't think of a way prooving what you said.. i thought to do a reduction from the complement of A(TM).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the language $\overline{\mathsf{EPSILON}_{\mathsf{CFG}}} = \{ <G, H>  \mid \text{$G$ and $H$ are CFGs and $L(G) \cap L(H) \neq \{\varepsilon\}$} \}$.

If $\overline{\mathsf{EPSILON}_{\mathsf{CFG}}}$ and $\mathsf{EPSILON}_{\mathsf{CFG}}$ were both recognizable, then they would both be decidable*. Since $\mathsf{EPSILON}_{\mathsf{CFG}}$ is not decidable, at least one of $\overline{\mathsf{EPSILON}_{\mathsf{CFG}}}$ and $\mathsf{EPSILON}_{\mathsf{CFG}}$ cannot be recognizable. It is not hard to show that $\overline{\mathsf{EPSILON}_{\mathsf{CFG}}}$ is recognizable, which implies that $\mathsf{EPSILON}_{\mathsf{CFG}}$ is not recognizable.

To see that $\overline{\mathsf{EPSILON}_{\mathsf{CFG}}}$ is recognizable, notice that the problem of deciding whether a word is generated by a CFG is decidable. Then we can test whether $G$ and $H$ both generate $\varepsilon$. If that's not the case, we can immediately accept. Otherwise we can iteratively consider each word $w \in \Sigma^* \setminus \{ \varepsilon\}$ and test whether $w$ is generated by both $G$ and $H$. If that's the case we accept.

---

*Altough $\overline{\mathsf{EPSILON}_{\mathsf{CFG}}}$ is not the complement of $\mathsf{EPSILON}_{\mathsf{CFG}}$, the only difference lies in the words that do not encode a valid pair of CFGs. However, for any reasonable encoding, is decidable to test whether a word encodes a valid pair of CFGs.

Comment: I'm not fully understanding the last part of your explanation..
https://prnt.sc/4qNj9eQz1sfB

Comment: I might be mistaken but I think the last part of "Otherwise....." is irrelevant. Because you already decided the input.

Comment: If it is not true that both $G$ and $H$ generate $\varepsilon$, then $L(H)\cap L(H)\neq \{\varepsilon\}$ and hence $\langle G,H\rangle$ is in $\overline{\mathsf{EPSILON}_{\mathsf{CFG}}}$. Notice that we did not already decide the language (if the condition does not hold, the algorithm continues. Besides we will only **accept** the language). Suppose now that both $G$ and $H$ generate $\varepsilon$. It might or might not be the case that  $L(H)\cap L(H)\neq\{\varepsilon\}$, depending on whether some other word $w$ is generated by both $G$ and $H$. This is checked by the "otherwise" part.

Comment: In case both G and H generate ε, then L(H)∩L(H)={ε(at least)}, hence it does not belong to EPSILONCFG¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯, why is there the need to keep iteratively search in the 'otherwise' part?

Comment: If both $G$ and $H$ generate $\varepsilon$ then both $L(G) \cap L(H) = \{\varepsilon\}$ and  $L(G) \cap L(H) \neq \{\varepsilon\}$ are still possible. To accept $\overline{\mathsf{EPSILON}_{\mathsf{CFG}}}$ you need to detect when the second case happens.  Consider these two examples: $L(G) = L(H) = \{ \varepsilon \}$ and $L(G) = L(H) = \{a, \varepsilon\}$. In the first example, $\langle G, H   \rangle \in \overline{\mathsf{EPSILON}_{\mathsf{CFG}}}$. In the second example, $\langle G, H   \rangle \not\in \overline{\mathsf{EPSILON}_{\mathsf{CFG}}}$

Comment: Now I see it!. Thanks a lot my dear friend :)